# How can we have @variable in JOOQ?

Tags: java, variables, jooq

I am trying to achieve something similar like the below MySql query in Jooq:

```
Select 
 CASE WHEN (datecolumn IS NULL) 
 THEN (@outerval:=@outerval+1) 
 ELSE (@outerval) END AS consec_set
From some_table;
```

How can we have @variable in JOOQ ?

Note: I am aware the equivalent for CASE WHEN in JOOQ but just want to know the @variable.

Jooq Version :3.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently not supported in jOOQ 3.0. I have registered a feature request for this:
https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2558

I'm not sure how much support for variables can really be added to jOOQ in a useful way. But in any case, you can always resort to plain SQL:

```
Field<Integer> f1 = DSL.field("@outerval:=@outerval+1", Integer.class);
Field<Integer> f2 = DSL.field("@outerval", Integer.class);
```

Comment: Thanks Lukas, I hope we will get the support in Jooq in near feature.

Comment: @SyedShahul: You're with [Venkat](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17324524/521799)? I'm sure we'll find a solution. However, such discussions might be off-topic for Stack Overflow