# Adding conditions to database queries in an orthogonal way

Tags: sql, parsing, multi-tenant, database

The problem at hand is how to add conditions to SQL database queries issued by pre-existing applications in an "orthogonal way", meaning that this operation should be done in such a way that applications need not be concerned. In case you are curious, the actual problem involves adding multitenancy-related criteria that should keep tenants from getting to each other data. In practical terms, that means adding extra conditions to WHERE clauses (in possibly multiple locations within the query).

My team has been working on a solution which involves "intercepting" and parsing the queries, before they are sent to the DBMS. As many of you probably know, SQL parsing is not the simplest thing to implement, especially when you need to support most of the major DBMS' syntax extensions.

Another idea which has been thrown around is that one could let the DBMS itself handle the criteria injection. It is, after all, the one element which has full knowledge over the query syntax and (hopefully) should have no problem tinkering with it before carrying out its execution. The problem then would be figuring out how to pass the multitenancy metadata to the DBMS. Is this viable at all? Is this a bad idea?

Any other ideas on how this problem might be approached?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Would it not be easier to work through views, each view restricted to the applicable user's data. The pre-written SQL could use a base name for the view which is then modified in code to add a prefix or suffix to the view name to give the user's view.

*Example:*

Table `tennant_data` has views named `tennant_data_user1` and `tennant_data_user2`.
Your SQL is `select col1, col2 from tennant_data_{view}`
Your program code obtains the name of the current user (user1 or user2), and replaces `{view}` with their userid in the SQL, then executes the SQL.

Depending upon the DBMS (and language?) you are using, you could probably grant access so that user1 can only use the xxx_user1 views and so on, so there is no chance of them accessing the wrong data be mis-using a view or direct access to the underlying table.

Answer (score 0):

#### Using server-side technology

The ideal place to implement this functionality is on the server side, of course. Some databases implement features like [Oracle's Virtual Private Database](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/security/index-088277.html) doing exactly what you need.

You could also emulate the feature by replacing all your direct table access by (possibly updatable) views, which contain a filter on relevant columns using [`SYS_CONTEXT`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions199.htm) (in Oracle). Using this approach, database clients will never be able to bypass those additional predicates that you will be adding everywhere.

#### Using client-side technology

You didn't mention the technology stack you are using, but in Java, this could be done with jOOQ. jOOQ ships with a SQL parser that can parse the SQL statement into an expression tree. One of the main use-cases for this is to translate SQL from one dialect to another, as can be seen here:

- https://www.jooq.org/translate
- [Top 5 Hidden jOOQ Features - Parsing Connection](https://blog.jooq.org/2018/01/12/top-5-hidden-jooq-features/#hidden5)

E.g. this statement that runs on SQL Server or PostgreSQL:

```java
try (DSLContext ctx = DSL.using("...");
     Connection c = ctx.parsingConnection(); // Magic here
     Statement s = c.createStatement();
     ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery(
         "SELECT * FROM (VALUES (1), (2), (3)) t(a)")) {

    while (rs.next())
        System.out.println(rs.getInt(1));
}
```

Could be translated to this equivalent statement in Oracle:

```sql
select t.a from (
  (select null a from dual where 1 = 0) union all
  (select * from (
    (select 1 from dual) union all
    (select 2 from dual) union all
    (select 3 from dual)
  ) t)
) t
```

Once you have the jOOQ expression tree available, you could transform it using jOOQ's `VisitListener` as can be seen in these articles:

- [Row Level Security implementation in JOOQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17330293/521799)
- [Implementing Client-Side Row-Level Security with jOOQ](https://blog.jooq.org/2015/06/17/implementing-client-side-row-level-security-with-jooq/)

#### Disclaimers:

- jOOQ can only parse the SQL functionality that is also supported by the jOOQ API. [The grammar can be seen here](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-parser/sql-parser-grammar/). This may not be enough for your existing applications, depending on how much vendor-specific functionality you're using.
- I work for the company behind jOOQ, so obviously, this answer is biased.