# JOOQ vs JDBC+tests

Tags: jdbc, jooq

What advantage have JOOQ over JDBC+tests?

In JDBC you can write SQL queries direct in code, with JOOQ we calls methods, so JOOQ is by default more slow.

In JOOQ is harder to do mistakes but not impossible. This mistakes can be caught in tests, with JOOQ you also should write these tests, so, no advantage here for JOOQ.

Answer (score 14):

I completely agree with you. It's always better to have tests, regardless if you're using a "dynamic language" (SQL as an external DSL, e.g. JDBC) or a "static language" (SQL as an internal DSL, e.g. jOOQ)

#### But there's much more than that:

You seem to have scratched only the surface of what jOOQ can do for you. Sure, type safe, embedded SQL is a great feature, but once you have that, you get for free (list is far from exhaustive):

- Active records: With JDBC, you're back to spelling out each individual boring `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` statement manually. jOOQ's [`UpdatableRecord`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/%C3%B6atest/org/jooq/UpdatableRecord.html) greatly simplifies this, while offering things like:

  - [`RecordListener`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/RecordListener.html) for record lifecycle management
  - [Optimistic locking](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/crud-with-updatablerecords/optimistic-locking/)
  - [Batching of inserts, updates, deletes](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/crud-with-updatablerecords/batch-execution-for-crud/)
- Dynamic SQL is very easy. Instead of that JDBC string concatenation mess that you'd be getting otherwise, [you can just dynamically add clauses to your SQL statements](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/dynamic-sql/).
- Multi tenancy: [You can easily switch schema references and/or table references at runtime](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/dsl-context/runtime-schema-mapping/) in order to run the same query against a different schema.
- Standardisation: The same jOOQ query runs on up to 21 RDBMS because the jOOQ API standardises the generated SQL. This can be seen in the [jOOQ manual's section about the `LIMIT` clause](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/select-statement/limit-clause/), for instance - one of SQL's most poorly standardised clauses
- Query Lifecycle: There's a simple SPI called [`ExecuteListener`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/ExecuteListener.html) that allows you to hook into the various JDBC interaction steps, including:

  - SQL generation
  - Prepared statement creation
  - Variable binding
  - Execution
  - Result fetching
  - Exceptions
- SQL transformation: The [`VisitListener`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/VisitListener.html) SPI allows you to intercept the SQL generation at any arbitrary position in your query expression tree. This can be very useful, e.g. to implement powerful things like [row level security](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17324524/521799).
- Stored procedures: These are rather tedious to bind to with JDBC, especially if you're using more advanced features like:

  - [Oracle's `TABLE` and `OBJECT` types](https://blog.jooq.org/2014/11/04/painless-access-from-java-to-plsql-procedures-with-jooq/) (imagine implementing `SQLData` et al.)
  - [Oracle's PL/SQL types](https://blog.jooq.org/2016/11/08/use-jooq-to-read-write-oracle-plsql-record-types/)
  - [Implicit cursors](https://blog.jooq.org/2017/02/08/how-to-fetch-oracle-12c-implicit-cursors-with-jdbc-and-jooq/)
  - [Table-valued functions](https://blog.jooq.org/2014/07/07/postgresqls-table-valued-functions/)

Of course, you get the compile-time type safety that you've mentioned (and IDE autocompletion) for free. And if you don't want to go all in on the internal DSL that jOOQ is offering, you can still just use [plain SQL](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql/) and then use jOOQ's API in a non-type safe way (which still has tons of features):

```java
// Just one example: CSV exports
String csvExport =
ctx.fetch("SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id = ?", 3)
   .formatCSV();
```

#### TL;DR:

- JDBC is a wire protocol abstraction API
- jOOQ is a SQL API

#### Disclaimer:

(Of course, this answer is biased as I work for the company behind jOOQ)

Comment: Using jOOQ is also more robust with respect to refactorings (due to the compile-time type safety). With plain JDBC it is way easier to miss updating a query when some DB object has been renamed or dropped. With an API like jOOQ the compiler will complain if something's amiss.

Comment: - Active records: you can add helpers to JDBC

- Dynamic SQL with JDBC: String select ="..."; String from = "..."; so the same mess
- Multi tenancy: how frequently do you change your schema in runtime? What about migrations? What about replications?
- Standardisation: in some databases you have functionality that miss in another, how it will be in JOOQ?

Comment: @Romper: *Helpers*: Yes, you can add helpers. But why reinvent the wheel? *Multi tenancy*: A lot of jOOQ users have this problem. YMMV. *Migrations*: [You can use Flyway for that](https://blog.jooq.org/2014/06/25/flyway-and-jooq-for-unbeatable-sql-development-productivity/). *Replications*: Curious about more details of your use-case. *Standardisation*: Sometimes, things can be emulated (see again [`LIMIT` clause](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/select-statement/limit-clause/))

Comment: About replications, if you have 3-4 instances of database, JOOQ will be able to change schema in runtime for all simultaneously? Yeap, emulated, and when you change database you think everything is ok, but code can do unexpected things

Comment: @RolandKrüger to avoid problems with updating a query you must have tests, same with JOOQ

Comment: @Romper: jOOQ will give you the tool to change the schema in runtime. You'll have to know yourself when to "switch". Sure, nothing is perfect and tests do help. From my experience, however, jOOQ does much much more than any homegrown wrapper around JDBC in the market, so it's a tradeoff most people are *very* happy to make. I just think you're asking the wrong question. The right question would be: How much does tackling your problems cost with: a) JDBC, b) jOOQ.

Comment: @Romper: yes, tests help. But you have to make sure that your tests sufficiently cover each and every case which should be achieved in theory but which is failed to achieve more often than not in practice. The compiler does not fail to point out any obscure corner case which might not be covered by a test. So, with a Java SQL API you can concentrate on writing those tests with the most benefit without having to manage a myriad of golden master SQL query string tests (remember the tests need to be refactored along with the db schema as well).

Comment: @RolandKrüger is the same with JOOQ, can you please show me code that need less tests with JOOQ that with JDBC?