# How can I implement row-level security with jOOQ?

Tags: java, jooq

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17324524/row-level-security-implementation-in-jooq) question, and [this](https://blog.jooq.org/implementing-client-side-row-level-security-with-jooq/) blog post. I'm not sure if this is relevant anymore (some deprecated code) and there might be a new and better way to do this.

Is there a way to add a condition to every query?

Our current solution is to add the following to every table with a Generator, and the developer has to apply these methods manually. Preferably this organization filter should be applied automatically to (almost) every query.

```java
public org.jooq.Condition filterNotDeleted() {
    return this.DELETED.eq(false);
}

public org.jooq.Condition filterOrganizationId(Long organizationId) {
    return this.ORGANIZATION_ID.eq(organizationId);
}

public org.jooq.Condition filterOrganizationIdAndNotDeleted(Long organizationId) {
    return this.DELETED.eq(false).and(this.ORGANIZATION_ID.eq(organizationId));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your links are still relevant, although, there are new options now instead of using a `VisitListener`, you can transform the query also with the new experimental [`Replacer` API](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/model-api/model-api-replacement/).

It's likely that a future jOOQ (not yet as of jOOQ 3.18) will support more row level security and multi tenancy use-cases out of the box, see [#2682](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2682).

Comment: I'm using the open source version of jOOQ, so I can't use the Replacer API. So my only option is the VisitListener, or can I also achieve this with the ExecuteListener?

Comment: @Disheart: Well, you can traverse the object model yourself, manually and patch the query from within the `ExecuteListener`, but that would just be manually re-implementing the `Replacer` API...