# How to set a @Variable in JOOQ

Tags: java, mysql, jooq

How can i use @variables using `JOOQ`?
(or is there a simpler possibility to show the line numbers? - note that i need to INSERT the selected data INTO another Table and the row_number shall always start at 0!)

```
SET @row_number = 0;

SELECT 
    (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS NUM, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME
FROM
    AUTHOR
LIMIT 5;
```

this is what i think the `JOOQ`code could look like...

```
Field<Integer> num = DSL.field("@row_number:=@row_number +1", Integer.class);
DSLContext create = DSL.using(connection, dialect);
create.select(AUTHOR.FIRST_NAME, AUTHOR.LAST_NAME, num)
      .from(AUTHOR)
      .limit(5)
      .fetch();
```

do i need to execute that

```
SET @row_number = 0;
```

with plain `JDBC` ?

i found the thing about variables and `JOOQ` here on StackOverflow - [how can we have variable in jooq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17318757/how-can-we-have-variable-in-jooq)

EDIT: i investigated a bit more and read that the results of this "solution" might change in future versions. ao i think about changing it to creating a temporary table with an pk identity (start at 0) then i have the same results but no user variable set and updates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've noticed, jOOQ doesn't currently strictly support your syntax, so you have to make use of the plain SQL templating mechanisms offered by the jOOQ API:
https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating

You've already done that correctly for the query itself. Now about initialising the variable, this is done ideally in the same JDBC statement, not in a separate statement to prevent side effects caused by jOOQ closing the JDBC connection between consecutive executions (e.g. when using a [`DataSourceConnectionProvider`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DataSourceConnectionProvider.html)). So, the most straightforward way to do that with jOOQ is to use an [`ExecuteListener`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/ExecuteListener.html) that prepends the initialisation SQL string to that particular statement only, e.g.

```java
class InitialisingVariableListener extends DefaultExecuteListener {
    @Override
    public void renderEnd(ExecuteContext ctx) {
        ctx.sql("SET @row_number = 0;" + ctx.sql());
    }
}
```

And hook that to your `Configuration` prior to executing the query:

```java
Field<Integer> num = DSL.field("@row_number:=@row_number +1", Integer.class);
DSLContext create = DSL.using(connection, dialect);
create.configuration().set(new InitialisingVariableListener());
create.select(AUTHOR.FIRST_NAME, AUTHOR.LAST_NAME, num)
      .from(AUTHOR)
      .limit(5)
      .fetch();
```

If you're reusing the `Configuration` among several queries, you may want to prefer to call `derive()` on it to create a new `Configuration` rather than `set()`, which modifies the `Configuration` for everyone.

#### A note on other RDBMS

This answer was MySQL specific, where the `SET` statement does not produce any output (update counts) through JDBC. In other RDBMS (e.g. PostgreSQL), `SET` produces an update count, which might have to be skipped, see this question here for details, and workarounds:

- [JOOQ: Mutli Tenancy with set session/local database variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76540584/521799)

Comment: at least in postgres this doesn't work.  You get a single row resultset with 0 in it which is the number of rows updated by the set command.

Full answer here
https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/discussions/15247

Comment: @Simbosan: This question was MySQL specific

Comment: It would be interesting if it was database specific rather than how Jooq handles multiple statements.  Thanks for your post it got me 95% of the way to the solution.

Comment: @Simbosan: I'll add a link to the related question (https://stackoverflow.com/q/76540584/521799) from my answer for better discoverability.